# Query document based on a reference to a cached object

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I have two types of objects `User` and `Company` whose data is stored in MongoDB collections `user` and `company`. `User` contains a reference to `Company`. I can query for user using the following code in the UserRepository:

```
$this
  ->createQueryBuilder()
  ->field('employer')->references($company);
```

`Company` however is a heavy used object which is cached using Redis. When no cache is present, everything works fine. But when the company instance was fetched from the cache. The Doctrine unit of work does not know about the instance. Executing the code above will therefore result in the following error:

```
Cannot create a DBRef for class App\Document\Company without an identifier. Have you forgotten to persist/merge the document first?
```

I have found out that I can use a hack to register the company with the unit of work after fetching it from Redis:

```
$company = $this->fetchFromCache($params);
$documentManager->getUnitOfWork()->registerManaged($company, $company->getId(), []);
```

However, this seems ugly. Is there a way that I can query for the users without having to let Doctrine know about the Company object, or changing my datamodel?

Comment: You might want to check in with the Doctrine-team about the status. It has been a milestone for many years, see https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/653

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately if you want to use ODM for querying you need to somehow let the ODM know about your object. While your `registerManaged` will work as it registers the document in the UnitOfWork it has a downside that any relations you might have there will be broken and/or Doctrine will assume they're new during persist/flush. You could try something along this:

```
$company = $this->fetchFromCache($params);
if ($dm->getUnitOfWork()->containsId($company->getId(), Company::class)) {
    return $dm->find(Company::class, $company->getId());
}
return $dm->merge($company);
```

As noted before, `merge` will recursively merge your documents and its embedded documents/relationships are and mark them as managed by ODM, just like they'd be just fetched. Please note that merging will conform to your [cascading settings](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2/reference/reference-mapping.html#cascading-operations) for references. More info about merging can be found [in the docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-documents). Also be aware that merging documents can affect already fetched documents and update their fields with what is being merged.

`Merge` operation will be only executed once as just before we're checking whether ODM already manages a company identified by an id fetched from the cache. If it does, we're calling `$dm->find()` which will not hit database as first it'll look up in-memory map of objects and return you the instance that is already managed. This way you'll always get a document managed by the ODM avoiding query to the database.